# Bounds on the Number of Vertices of a Polyhedron

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

This is an extension from Exercise 2.10 (a) of [Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis' *Introduction to Linear Optimization*](http://athenasc.com/linoptbook.html).

> **Exercise 2.10 (a)** Consider the standard form polyhedron $P=\{x\mid Ax=b,x\ge0\}$. Suppose that the matrix $A$ has dimensions $m\times n$ and that it rows are linearly independent. If $n=m+1$, then $P$ has at most two basic feasible solutions.

I can easily prove that this is true: Since $n=m+1$, then $\dim N(A)=1$, where $N(A)$ is the null space of $A$. Then we can write $N(A)=\text{span}\{d\}$ for some nonzero $d\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If $x,y,z$ are different BFS of $P$, then $x-y=c_1d$ and $y-z=c_2d$, where $c_1,c_2>0$ without loss of generality. But then
$$
y=\frac{c_2}{c_1+c_2}x+\frac{c_1}{c_1+c_2}z
$$
contradicts the fact that $y$ is an extreme point.

My question is as follows:

> Is there an upper bound for the number of BFS of polyhedra with $n-m=2$?

I tried to apply the same trick of the proof above, but it no longer works. In the one-dimensional case, if distinct $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\text{span}\{d\}$, then there always exist $i,j,k$ distinct such that $x_i\in\text{conv}\{x_j,x_k\}$. However, in the two-dimensional case, there exist distinct $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\in\text{span}\{d_1,d_2\}$ such that for all combinations $(i,j,k,\ell)$, $x_i\not\in\text{conv}\{x_j,x_k,x_{\ell}\}$ always.

I also tried to compute the numbers of BFS of some polyehdra with $n-m=2$ (with small $m$ and $n$ of course). In the examples I tried, the number of BFS is always no larger $4$.

Is there a way to prove this or disprove this? More generally:

> Apart from the trivial upper bound $\binom{m}{n}$, are there other lower and upper bounds on the numbers of vertices for standard form polyhedra for fixed $(m,n)$?